# Filter WooCommerce products from their description

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce, filter, product

I'm creating Web Shop that sells tech and that kind of products. Client wants filters to search descriptions of the products and to filter it by that. For example: Let's say 10 out of 50 products have 'i7' in their descriptions. I created the code that searches every products description and filters it correctly. Firstly, I created so that i search the term i want to filter, later i was planning on adding usual filters so that user can just click on it. Nevertheless, when i search 'i7' it just prints IDs of the products that contain 'i7' in their description below the search button. I want it to show only that products in Shop section where all products show, so basically to show it like regular filters.

Here's the code of the "filter" i created:

```
function product_filter_plugin_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('product-filter-plugin-script', plugins_url('/assets/js/product-filter-plugin.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_style('product-filter-plugin-style', plugins_url('/assets/css/product-filter-plugin.css', __FILE__), array(), '1.0.0');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'product_filter_plugin_enqueue_scripts');

// Handle the filtering functionality
function product_filter_plugin_handle_filtering() {
    // Check if a search query is submitted
    if (isset($_GET['search_query'])) {
        $search_query = sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_query']);

        // Set up the query arguments
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );

        // Query the products
        $products_query = new WP_Query($args);

        // Array to store filtered product IDs
        $filtered_product_ids = array();

        // Loop through each product and filter based on the search query
        if ($products_query->have_posts()) {
            while ($products_query->have_posts()) {
                $products_query->the_post();
                $product_id = get_the_ID();
                $product_description = get_the_content();

                // Filter based on the search query
                if (strpos($product_description, $search_query) !== false) {
                    // Add the filtered product ID to the array
                    $filtered_product_ids[] = $product_id;
                }
            }
        }

        // Reset the post data
        wp_reset_postdata();

        // Save the filtered product IDs to a file
        $filtered_ids_file_path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'filter_id.txt';
        file_put_contents($filtered_ids_file_path, implode(',', $filtered_product_ids));


        return $filtered_product_ids;
    }
}

// Create a shortcode for the filtering functionality
function product_filter_plugin_shortcode($atts) {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="product-filter-container">
        <form class="product-filter-form" action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" method="GET">
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
            <input type="text" name="search_query" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" placeholder="Pretraga artikala">
            <input type="submit" value="Pretraži">
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php

    // Check if the current page is the shop page
    if (is_shop()) {
        $global_filtered_product_ids = product_filter_plugin_handle_filtering();
        if (!empty($global_filtered_product_ids)) {
            echo '<div class="product-filter-results">';
            echo "ID: " . implode(', ', $global_filtered_product_ids);
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('product_filter', 'product_filter_plugin_shortcode');
```

```
/* product-filter-plugin.js */

(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Submit the filter form on enter key press in the input field
      $('.product-filter-form input[type="text"]').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('.product-filter-form').submit();
        }
      });
    });
  })(jQuery);
```

```
/* product-filter-plugin.css */

.product-filter-container {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  .product-filter-form input[type="text"] {
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  
  .product-filter-results {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  
  .product-filter-results .product-item {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
```

Any help is good. Thanks in advance

I tried using ChatGPT but it's not that advanced yet. I tried adding code to the functions.php of my theme but it's not working.

It prints out this: [prints below search button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fGyf.png)

But, I want it to be here:

[prints where all other products usually be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN74W.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, in your jQuery code, `(function($){ })(jQuery);` already includes the `ready()` event, so you don't need `$(document).ready(function() {`.

Now there is a much lighter and efficient way to filter directly products from their description. Try the following revisited code version:

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'product_filter_plugin_enqueue_scripts');
function product_filter_plugin_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('product-filter-plugin-script', plugins_url('/assets/js/product-filter-plugin.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_style('product-filter-plugin-style', plugins_url('/assets/css/product-filter-plugin.css', __FILE__), array(), '1.0.0');
}

// Create a shortcode for the filtering functionality
add_shortcode('product_filter', 'product_filter_plugin_shortcode');
function product_filter_plugin_shortcode($atts) {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="product-filter-container">
        <form class="product-filter-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ); ?>" method="GET">
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
            <input type="text" name="search_query" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" placeholder="Search articles">
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}

// Filter products from their description
add_filter('posts_clauses', 'filter_from_product_description', 10, 2 );
function filter_from_product_description( $clauses, $query ) {

    if( is_shop() && isset($_GET['search_query']) && ! empty($_GET['search_query']) && $query->is_post_type_archive('product') ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $string = esc_attr($_GET['search_query']);

        $clauses['where'] .= " AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_content LIKE '%{$string}%' ";
    }
    return $clauses;
}
```

The jQuery code in `product-filter-plugin.js` file:

```js
(function($) {
    $('.product-filter-form input[type="text"]').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.product-filter-form').submit();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The CSS stays unchanged.

Tested and works.

Answer (score -1):

You're close to the solution! The main thing to achieve this is to use WordPress's pre_get_posts action hook to alter the main query based on your search_query.

Step 1: Use the pre_get_posts action hook

```
    function product_filter_plugin_pre_get_posts($query) {
    // Check if it's the main query, a product query, and there's a search_query parameter
    if ($query->is_main_query() && isset($_GET['search_query']) && !empty($_GET['search_query']) && $query->get('post_type') === 'product') {
        $search_query = sanitize_text_field($_GET['search_query']);
        $filtered_product_ids = product_filter_plugin_handle_filtering();
        // Modify the main query to only get products with the filtered IDs
        $query->set('post__in', $filtered_product_ids);
    }
 }
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'product_filter_plugin_pre_get_posts');
```

**Step 2:** Update your shortcode
Remove the part where you output the filtered product IDs, as the main WooCommerce loop will handle the display.

```
function product_filter_plugin_shortcode($atts) {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="product-filter-container">
        <form class="product-filter-form" action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/shop/')); ?>" method="GET">
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
            <input type="text" name="search_query" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" placeholder="Pretraga artikala">
            <input type="submit" value="Pretraži">
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

**Step 3:** Ensure your theme supports filtering
Ensure the WooCommerce templates in your theme use the main WordPress query. If the theme has a custom WP_Query for the shop page, it might bypass the filtering.

Final thoughts: After these changes, searching for a term will redirect you to the shop page, showing only the products that match the criteria in their descriptions. Always test thoroughly, especially when altering the main query!

Comment: What should product_filter_plugin_handle_filtering look like?